# How do I find size of varying rows of a dynamically allocated array?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
int *exceptions[7];
int a[] = {1, 4, 11, 13};
int b[] = {5, 6, 11, 12, 14, 15};
int c[] = {2, 12, 14, 15};
int d[] = {1, 4, 7, 9, 10, 15};
int e[] = {1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9};
int f[] = {1, 2, 3, 7, 13};
int g[] = {0, 1, 7, 12};

exceptions[0] = a;
exceptions[1] = b;
exceptions[2] = c;
exceptions[3] = d;
exceptions[4] = e;
exceptions[5] = f;
exceptions[6] = g;
```

Size of `exception[0]` and `exception[1]` should be `4` and `6` respectively.

Here's my code:

```
short size = sizeof(exceptions[1]) / sizeof(exceptions[1][0]);
```

But I'm getting `2` for every row. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You don't.  There's no way to tell the size of an array from a pointer into it.

Comment: There is no dynamic allocation here.

Comment: Please read the documentation of `sizeof`

Answer (score 3):

```
 short size = sizeof(exceptions[1]) / sizeof(exceptions[1][0]);
```

effectively does the same as

```
 short size = sizeof(int*) / sizeof(int);
```

On a 64 bit platform, that yields most probably `2`.

---

> How can I solve this problem?

Use some c++ standard container like `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` instead:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> exceptions {
    {1, 4, 11, 13},
    {5, 6, 11, 12, 14, 15},
    {2, 12, 14, 15},
    {1, 4, 7, 9, 10, 15},
    {1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9},
    {1, 2, 3, 7, 13},
    {0, 1, 7, 12},
}
```

Your statement will become:

```
 short size = exceptions[0].size();
 size = exceptions[1].size();
```

(for whatever that's needed)

Comment: You can also store a separate array with sizes or store a final element as some null termination value like `-1` or `nan` and iterate to find size. This is gross though, so it can stay down here in the comments.

Comment: Maybe add though, that you can use `std::array` if you want to keep the stack allocation style.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox `std::array`'s sizes must be fixed at compile time, so you have to provide these beforehand as template parameters. Not so convenient.

Comment: True, but the OP has static sized arrays anyway. A `std::array` approach would be closer to the OP's initial code.

Answer (score 0):

The best remedy would be to use vector provided in standard template library. They have a size() function which you can use and they are much more versatile than array.